# Error with Data Adapter with select2 4

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to use more than 10000 datas in my combobox and  I have this code

```
$.fn.select2.amd.define('select2/data/customAdapter',[
        'select2/data/array',
        'select2/utils'
    ],
    function (ArrayAdapter, Utils) {

        function CustomDataAdapter ($element, options) {
            CustomDataAdapter.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
        }
        Utils.Extend(CustomDataAdapter, ArrayAdapter);

        CustomDataAdapter.prototype.query = function (params,callback) {
            console.log(params);
           var pageSize,
                    results;
                    pageSize = 20;
                    results  = _.filter(content, function (e) {
                        return (params.term === "" || e.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0);
                 });
                 console.log(results);
                 callback({
                    results: results.slice((params.page - 1) * pageSize, params.page * pageSize),
                    // retrieve more when user hits bottom
                    more   : results.length >= params.page * pageSize
                });
        };

        return CustomDataAdapter;
    }
);

var customAdapter=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/customAdapter');
    objCmb.select2({
        allowClear: true, 
        disabled: dis, 
        placeholder: Empty, 
        data: content, 
        formatLoadMore   : 'Loading more...',
        dataAdapter:customAdapter

    });
```

when I use the select2  this error appear

TypeError: params.term is undefined

...ms.term === "" || e.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when someone focuses the select2 control, there's no really a `term`, so the `params` object is empty (e.g. `{}`). You can see this in [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srxyj1v2/) (just try to search for something).

If you want to get rid of that error, you can modify your custom `query` function to account for that:

```
CustomDataAdapter.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
    var pageSize, results;
    pageSize = 20;
    results = _.filter(content, function (e) {
        return (params.term == null || params.term === "" || e.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0);
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
    callback({
        results: results.slice((params.page - 1) * pageSize, params.page * pageSize),
        more: results.length >= params.page * pageSize
    });
};
```

This will be working as you'd expect it to ([modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srxyj1v2/1/)).

I would also like to note that your code example does not include the `select` population with items, so it's not present in the above fiddles either.